# loop for ggplot2 formula in r

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

Here is an example:

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()

yintercept <- c(5, 12, 20, 28, 29, 40)
col <- c("red", "blue", "green", "pink", "yellow", "tan")

# for the first level yintercept, and col 
p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 5), col = "red")
```

I have more levels of variables as listed above, instead of writing long "+" formula, can I loop the process. Sorry for simple question.

**Edits:** how to loop over the x or y variables in the formula

```
   myd <- data.frame (y = rnorm (100, 5, 10), X1 = rnorm (100, 5, 1), 
    X3 = rnorm (100, 10, 2), X4 = rnorm (100, 50,4))

x <- c("X1",  "X2",   "X3", "X4")

p <- ggplot(myd, aes(y = y)) + 
 mapply ( function (x) (geom_point(x = aes_string (x))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **ggplot2** way to do this is to *always* put data in a data frame and map the aesthetic. It makes things much simpler:

```
df <- data.frame(yint = yintercept)

# for the first level yintercept, and col 
p + geom_hline(data = df,aes(yintercept=yint,colour = factor(yint))) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = col,guide = "none")
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer, I have still question if name of x or y aes can be still looped in the same as colour or intercept...see my recent edits

Comment: That sort of thing _can_ be done, in principle, though probably not the way you sketched out. However, that usually isn't a _good_ way to go about things (at least not for the sort of example you provide). The only exception would be if its more or less _impossible_ to arrange your data in a data frame, but you haven't provided an example where that would be the case.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
p+mapply(function(a,b){dum<-aes_string(yintercept=a);
                       geom_hline(dum, col = b)},a=yintercept,b=col)
```

Comment: You don't need the semicolon.